# Как исправить ошибку 404 на сайте?

Tags: php, .htaccess, битрикс

Не могу исправить эту ошибку: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Сайт: https://vkinodoma.ru

CMS: Bitrix Start

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или подскажите с чем связана, чтобы знать куда копать.

Comment: Я бы для начала посмотрел логи nginx

Comment: Логи добавил и код от 404.php тоже

Comment: Не находит класс CHTTP, нужно посмотреть где он находится и понять, как поправить импорт

Comment: Проблема решена.
Оказалось, что компонент "Портфолио" на главной странице криво был подключен.